# Java reconnect after network interface change

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x, java-6, sardine

I am writing a file synchronization client (in Java 1.6) that uses Sardine:

https://code.google.com/p/sardine/

When Sardine loses connection to the server (ie. network outage or change from LAN to WiFi), I am unable to reconnect until I completely stop the client and start it back up again.

I've tried the following:

- spamming the connection
- re-creating the Sardine object dynamically
- re-packaging Sardine source code with latest Apache HTTP libs

As far as I can tell the actual networking takes place within [AbstractHttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/AbstractHttpClient.html), but I am not sure what to try next.

**Any suggestions on how I can make this thing re-connect dynamically regardless of the reason?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to shutdown your sardine object and create another one, example:

```
Sardine sardine = SardineFactory.begin();

sardine.createDirectory(url);

if (sardine != null) {
    sardine.shutdown();
}

sardine = SardineFactory.begin();

// use again
```